# R StackApply: create an 8-day index from daily data while accounting for year

Tags: r, indexing, raster, r-raster

I would like to create an index that I can use in StackApply for aggregating a daily rainfall raster stack into 8-day sums while accounting for the year. Let me illustrate with some code. Here's what a normal sequential daily data looks like:

```
> seq.Date(as.Date("2001-11-01"), as.Date("2002-01-31"),by=1)
 [1] "2001-11-01" "2001-11-02" "2001-11-03" "2001-11-04" "2001-11-05" "2001-11-06" "2001-11-07"
 [8] "2001-11-08" "2001-11-09" "2001-11-10" "2001-11-11" "2001-11-12" "2001-11-13" "2001-11-14"
[15] "2001-11-15" "2001-11-16" "2001-11-17" "2001-11-18" "2001-11-19" "2001-11-20" "2001-11-21"
[22] "2001-11-22" "2001-11-23" "2001-11-24" "2001-11-25" "2001-11-26" "2001-11-27" "2001-11-28"
[29] "2001-11-29" "2001-11-30" "2001-12-01" "2001-12-02" "2001-12-03" "2001-12-04" "2001-12-05"
[36] "2001-12-06" "2001-12-07" "2001-12-08" "2001-12-09" "2001-12-10" "2001-12-11" "2001-12-12"
[43] "2001-12-13" "2001-12-14" "2001-12-15" "2001-12-16" "2001-12-17" "2001-12-18" "2001-12-19"
[50] "2001-12-20" "2001-12-21" "2001-12-22" "2001-12-23" "2001-12-24" "2001-12-25" "2001-12-26"
[57] "2001-12-27" "2001-12-28" "2001-12-29" "2001-12-30" "2001-12-31" "2002-01-01" "2002-01-02"
[64] "2002-01-03" "2002-01-04" "2002-01-05" "2002-01-06" "2002-01-07" "2002-01-08" "2002-01-09"
[71] "2002-01-10" "2002-01-11" "2002-01-12" "2002-01-13" "2002-01-14" "2002-01-15" "2002-01-16"
[78] "2002-01-17" "2002-01-18" "2002-01-19" "2002-01-20" "2002-01-21" "2002-01-22" "2002-01-23"
[85] "2002-01-24" "2002-01-25" "2002-01-26" "2002-01-27" "2002-01-28" "2002-01-29" "2002-01-30"
[92] "2002-01-31"
```

Here is what it looks like if I sequence those daily values into 8-day intervals:

```
> seq.Date(as.Date("2001-11-01"), as.Date("2002-01-31"),by=8)
 [1] "2001-11-01" "2001-11-09" "2001-11-17" "2001-11-25" "2001-12-03" "2001-12-11" "2001-12-19"
 [8] "2001-12-27" "2002-01-04" "2002-01-12" "2002-01-20" "2002-01-28"
```

It wraps over to the following year just as it does from one month to the next (monthly wrap-over is fine). This is only a part of the problem because I would like the end product to be an index that I can use in StackApply. So, taking the 8-day example above, the index should look like this:

```
> rep(1:12,times=c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,5,8,8,8,7))
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
[32]  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  9
[63]  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
```

Note the 5 in the middle of the command, which indicates that it stops at December 31st 2001 and does not wrap over to 2002. In summary, I want to create an index that has a single integer for each 8-day interval throughout the year but that does not carry over the next year. I have a raster stack of over 20 years of daily data so this will be a very long index.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Would combining `lubridate::yday()` and `%% 8` solve your problem?

Comment: You mean this `lubridate::yday(x = seq.Date(as.Date("2001-11-01"), as.Date("2002-01-31"),by=1)) %% 8`? The output is close but not exactly how the index should be.

Comment: `dat <- seq.Date(as.Date("2001-11-01"), as.Date("2002-01-31"),by=1);
ref <- seq.Date(as.Date("2001-11-01"), as.Date("2002-01-31"),by=8);
out <- sapply(dat,function(x){sum(x - ref >=0)})` is really close but I'm unsure about why you want `2002-01-01` to `2002-01-04` when everything else rounds down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a bit of a workaround but this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"), "day"))

df %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(index = rep(seq_along(df$date), each = 8)[1:max(yday(date))]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(index = index + 46 * (year - min(year)))
```

Comment: Your welcome. BTW, just realized that this only works in case you have no missing dates and each year starts at January 1st and ends at December 31st. This code could of course be modified for more general cases.

Comment: You're right. I realized that as well, I haven't sifted through all my data points for missing values because the 8-day intervals seems generally consistent. As for the dates, they do begin Jan 1st and end Dec 31st, but as you said, I can modify the script. @Lennyy, perhaps you can edit your answer so it reflects these other scenarios in case someone has a slightly different but overall similar problem?